# $\bar{S}(x,r)$, does not contain all y with $\rho(x,y)\leq r$

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading Rudin's Real and complex analysis, he mentioned there exist situations in which
$\bar{S}(x,r)$, does not contain all y with $\rho(x,y)\leq r$, $S(x,r)$ is the open ball of $x$.
Could someone help to explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X = [-1, 1] \cup \{-2, 2\}$ with the Euclidean distance. $\overline{S}(0, 2)$ doesn't contain $\{-2, 2\}$.

Comment: Or $\mathbb{N}$ with the Euclidean distance.